# Simplifying complex expressions

Tags: simplifying-expressions, complex, assumptions

I'm trying to work with complexes and I want *Mathematica* to know that all variables are real unless I explicitly assigned the variable with an `I` so I wrote:

```
$Assumptions = Except[I,_] ∈ Reals
```

It worked fine for simple expressions

```
f = Exp[-I*a] * a + Exp[-I*b]
Simplify[Conjugate[f]]
```

> Exp[I*a] * a + Exp[I*b]

but for a more complex expression:

```
g = Exp[-I*a] * a + Exp[-I*b] * b
Simplify[Conjugate[g]]
```

> Exp[-I*a] * a + Exp[-I*b] * b

which is wrong. What can I do about it?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use Except in $Assumptions like you do.
 Just use ComplexExpand which assumes that are variables are real. 
E.g.:

```
conj = TrigToExp@ComplexExpand@Conjugate@# &;
```

Then

```
  conj[ Exp[-I*a]*a + Exp[-I*b]*b ]
```

gives

```
  a*E^(I*a) + b*E^(I*b)
```